# Nullhomotopy generalization.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

If we have a $k$-dim *proper* smooth submanifold $N \varsubsetneq M$  and  a continuous map $r|_{N } : M \to  N$ that is the identity (the map $r$ restricted to $N$ is identity on $N$). Must the inclusion $i: N \hookrightarrow M$ be nullhomotopic?

I hypothesize that this further shows that for any smooth manifold $W$ diffeomorphic to $N$, we cannot have $i: W \hookrightarrow M$ being nullhomotopic. Is there anything wrong with this generalization? This is my question.

After looking at Kevin's remark, it appears the result is true if $S^n \times S^n \times \dots \times S^n = W$. I am reducing the case to $S^n \times S^n$. So let $i : S^n \times S^n \hookrightarrow N$ and $r: N \to S^n \times S^n \cong N \subset M$. By definition, $r = id_N$. Now this means $i \circ r  \simeq id_N \neq p$ for a fixed $p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason at all that $i$ should be nullhomotopic. Consider, for instance, $N=M$, or $M\to S^1\times M$.

**EDIT**: Your attempted generalization is false. Consider two inclusions of the circle $S^1$ into the solid torus $S^1\times D^2$, as respectively the $S^1$ coordinate and the boundary of the $D^2$ coordinate. The first inclusion is not nullhomotopic but the second is. I realize you haven't written down your computation for the first part of the question, but what you've started with seems unlikely to lead anywhere useful.

Comment: Well, still. Include $M$ into $M\times I$, or if you want a proper submanifold of a closed manifold, into $M\times S^1$.

Comment: Consider $f: S^2 \times R \to S^2: (x, t) \mapsto x$.

Comment: @JohnHughes, I take it you want $R = [0,1]$ right? Your homotopy goes back to Kevin's case.

Comment: No, I meant $\mathbb R$. So my $M$ is an open manifold of dimension 3, projecting to a closed submanifold of dimension 2, but the map is not nullhomotopic. I think Kevin's example w/ $M \times S^1$ doesn't work, as his map goes from $N$ (the submanifold) into the manifold $M$, rather than from $M$ onto $N$. Of course, the projection $S^2 \times S^1 \to S^2 : (x, y) \mapsto x$ *does* work fine, and it's perhaps simpler than my example, since everything is compact.)

Comment: OK, you didn't write down what you claim you wrote down. Are you trying to show that if $i$ is not nullhomotopic, then there is no nullhomotopic inclusion of a manifold diffeomorphic to $N$ into $M$?

Comment: @KevinCarlson, does the edit clarify? But to answer you quickly, half of my question is what you said. But I need to verify the first part first because the second follows easily (as a corollary) from the diffeomorphic properties.

Comment: I've edited. Unless I'm misinterpreting, your generalization has nothing to support it.

Comment: Actually from your example it looks like the statement is true if $N \cong S^n \times S^n$ (it went right past through me, as well as John's. Now i just have to come up with some convincing argument..Because your inclusion, if I understand you correctly is $i(x) = (x,y)$ with $x \in S^1$ and $y \in D^2.$.

Comment: You're now claiming that if there's any nullhomotopic inclusion of $S^n\times S^n$ into $M$ then all such inclusions are nullhomotopic? Why? And for a counterexample, just cut a solid torus out of $\mathbb{R}^3$.